Book-ID about teenage(?) guy that uses monster's souls to get new abilities
I read a book maybe 2-3 years ago about a teenage (I think) boy that has the ability to steal the souls of monster's to steal abilities from them. I think there was something about taking the soul's of people too?
He was in some kind of group with other people his own age, and they had abilities too. The mc was special though for some reason, somehow fundamentally different from everyone else (I think). I feel like they might have been students, or were training under someone.
I think they worshipped a chair or something as their queen/a star or something like that?
Vaguely implied, but the setting was medieval-ish (no modern weapons, just swords and the like).
Also, I think the night was some kind of evil entity (I know it spawned the monsters for sure though)?
There was more than one book in the series, and I think there were more to come.
It was through KU (Kindle Unlimited).
I think I remember the author's name sounding vaguely Spanish-ish.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover of the book?

Do you remember whether did you read it online or was it a physical copy. And if later, was it soft or hard cover. And was it a lit-rpg?

@DavidW Sorry, no.

@Negdo I read it through KU (Kindle Unlimited), and I don't think it was a LitRPG (more cultivation-y, I think).

I found it!
The first book is called Awakening Arte. The series is called The Eldest Throne, which currently has two books. The author is Bernie Anés Paz.

Roun was born clanless, depriving him of a future in an empire where bloodlines and reputation mean everything. His only hope for escaping the life of an outcast lies in being awakened by the Eldest Throne and becoming a guardian of humanity.
But when his dream finally comes true, Roun finds himself stranded on the path to immortality with only a fragment of the spiritual powers he should have received. Roun, however, is used to making do with less—and will let neither rigorous training nor grotesque chimeras stand in the way of his ascension.
To find his own path, he will need to search for the answers hidden within. What he uncovers will forge him into a hero unlike any other—if it doesn't leave him an abomination first.


You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. You have to wait until 48 hours after asking for a self-answer, but we're well past that. You may also want to [edit] matching details into your answer to help others. Oh, and how did you find it?

@FuzzyBoots I was looking for more books to read on KU when I came across it. I thought the cover looked interesting, so I opened it and read the summary, and saw it was familiar. I checked here, and it matched. I read it, and verified for sure.

Could this be Vigor Mortis, by Natalie Maher? The protagonist is a girl, not a boy, but it's a possible match because she ate souls, was in a group of similar-age people as part of a larger organization, and was special for having the forbidden skill of necromancy, which allowed her to eat souls and put them into bodies.
It seems it was turned into a book, but I originally read it online on Royal Road.

No, I don't think so. The mc didn't put the souls into bodies, just absorbed them and used that to steal an ability that the monster had.
